# why this huge disparity in maximum row sizes between PostgreSQL and Sybase ASE

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, sybase-ase

PostgeSQL has some ridiculously ample field and row size limits (1GB and 1.6TB respectively).

Sybase ASE on the other hand has row size limits in the neighborhood of 4 or 8KB.

E.g. on a Sybase ASE 15.7 I see:

```
sqldev.mydatabase.1> create table foo2(a VARCHAR(7000));
Warning: Row size (7034 bytes) could exceed row size limit, which is 1962 bytes
```

This isn't just a warning about performance as it is actually enforced when I try to insert something larger than 1962 bytes:

```
Attempt to update or insert row failed because resultant row of size 4462 bytes is larger than the maximum size (1962 bytes) allowed for this table.
Command has been aborted.
```

I guess that similar limits apply to SQL Server on account of common heritage and Google seems to agree (but I haven't tried that on SQL Server).

I hypothesize that this huge disparity must be the result of some widely different architectural decisions or some fundamental trade-off that was decided different ways with each RDBMS. If this is right then what trade-off or architectural decision would that be?

Comment: I will find it very weird if Sybase doesn't have other options (types) for storing lengthy text. What are the possible character types? (I've searched briefly but there are so many versions and editions that I'm not sure if my findings match your version. I found `LONG VARCHAR` which can hold up to 2GB and `CLOB` with up to 512TB).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It does have other options. You can use TEXT but that comes  with a different programming API than ordinary VARCHARs and has some other nuisances as well (e.g. database browser tools like DbAdmin don't render the TEXT columns).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as **SQL Server** is concerned:

I'm not sure what you mean - you can store plenty of LOB data in a `varchar(max)` / `nvarchar(max)` / `varbinary(max)` column (up to 2GB).

You seem to be stuck on page size - yes a single page is limited to 8kb, and yes you are limited to 8060 bytes for *non-LOB* data, but no you can put plenty more than that into a table - it just can't all be held on a single page. Here is a table with one column, having one row, and the data is 136kb (216kb reserved):

```
CREATE TABLE #x(a varchar(max));
INSERT #x SELECT REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'a'), 100000);
SELECT DATALENGTH(a) FROM #x; -- 100,000    
EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_spaceused @objname = N'#x'; 
     -- 1 row, 216kb reserved, 136kb data size
DROP TABLE #x;
```

You can of course go much bigger:

- Change the `REPLICATE` command to 10,000,000 and you get the same 1 row with 10,016kb of data (10,088kb reserved).
- 100 million? 99kb
- A billion? Takes a little longer, but still demonstrable... 997k.

From [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx):

> SQL Server supports row-overflow storage which enables variable length columns to be pushed off-row. Only a 24-byte root is stored in the main record for variable length columns pushed out of row; because of this, the effective row limit is higher than in previous releases of SQL Server. For more information, see the "[Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981.aspx)" topic in SQL Server Books Online.

Some of this changes with Columnstore (which uses different storage) and In-Memory OLTP (which still has limits, but [Table and Row Size in Memory-Optimized Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205318.aspx) might be good to read up on if you are (or might be) using In-Memory OLTP).

*I don't know enough about PostgreSQL to comment on that platform, but as this was framed as a limitation in SQL Server, I felt the need to defend it (even if I can't defend Sybase similarly - it is not unlike SQL Server, but I confess I don't know the specifics).*